# Begin for loop every time where it ended last

Tags: bash, for

I have roughly 1 million images on a directory.  The files were numbered from 1 to n.  I am using for loop to iterate over each image.  Since each iteration is checked by individuals, only certain number of iterations could be done in a day.  When I begin the loop again the subsequent day, the loop obviously begins from the first file again.

I saved the files iterated through the loop in a text file and read the last line of the text file before the loop starts every time.  I am trying to use the last read file as a beginning for the for loop.

The following is the code done so far:

```
query=/ImageFolder/*.jpg
fil=$( tail -n 1 readfiles.txt )

for f in $query
    do
      python ~/runprog.py --query $f
    done
```

I am not sure how to use the $fil as my starting point in the for loop and the start iterating subsequent files from thereon.

Comment: You could, once you processed an image, move this image to a different directory, say `to_be_reviewed`.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you...I tried this with a small set of images...and it worked...but since the size of images were big and also were in large numbers....I wanted to keep all the images in just one file.

Comment: You all pictures in the same **file**? For sure you don't. You have them in the same **folder**. BTW, moving the file to a different folder doesn't take longer for large pictures than for small ones, as long as both folders are in the same file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `readfiles.txt` contains all already processed files, you can use `grep` to look up if a certain was done or not.

After running the python script, update that file with the processed file.

```
for f in /ImageFolder/*.jpg; do
   if ! grep -q "$f" readfiles.txt; then 
      python ~/runprog.py --query "$f"
      echo "$f" >> readfiles.txt
   fi
done
```

Comment: excellent...thank you.  Works like a charm.  I was struggling and stuck with using the last file.